# JQuery: .text() get the html within a node, how do I set the text within a node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery, I can do the following to get the text within my `LI`

```
$("#listingTabs li").eq(2).text();
```

How do I **set** the text? Because the following doesn't work

```
$("#listingTabs li").eq(2).text() = 'insert new text';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#listingTabs li").eq(2).text("insert new text");
```

You can also set the innerHTML of the li using

```
$("#listingTabs li").eq(2).html("<b>insert new text</b>");
```

Comment: What about -->  $("#listingTabs li").eq(2).html('insert new text'); ?

Comment: neither is better - they do different things... pick the one that does what you want it to do

Comment: the text() function will automatically escape HTML tags, so blah.text('<b>boo</b>') will set the text to "<b>boo</b>", whereas if you used blah.html() then you would get "boo" in bold.

Comment: @Dave, I don't understand - can you explain in more detail. That still sounds like you get the same resulting even using a <b> bold tag

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#listingTabs li").eq(2).text('insert new text');
```

Answer (score 4):

The `text()` function works as both a getter and a setter.  Try this:

```
$("#listingTabs li").eq(2).text('insert new text');
```

If you give it a parameter, it acts as a setter for that property.  If you don't, it acts as a getter.

Comment: What about -->  $("#listingTabs li").eq(2).html('insert new text'); ?

Comment: The `html()` function basically sets and retrieves the `innerHTML` property of an element.  There can be subtle differences between `text()` and `html()` for an element, depending on the markup inside the element.

Comment: For an `<li>`, the `html()` and `text()` functions will do the same thing if you just have plain text inside the `<li></li>` tags.  If you put markup such as a `<span>` tag in there, you will see differences in the results.

Comment: @zombat, what happens if I have markup inside the insert like "insert <b>bold</b> text". what's the difference now?

Comment: It's probably taking you longer to type out that question than it would to test it, but if you have markup inside your text string, you need to use the `html()` function to set it.